# Как оформить текст письма в художественном произведении, какие варианты допустимы?

Tags: кавычки, оформление-текста, цитирование, оформление-книги, курсив

Скажите, пожалуйста, как лучше оформить текст письма, которое приводится в художественном произведении? Есть ли рекомендации на сей счёт? Например, в книге "Гарри Поттер и Кубок огня" (Джоан Роулинг, изд. "РОСМЭН-ПРЕСС", 2002 г.) тексты писем выделены курсивом и отделены от основного текста пустыми строками.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Какие ещё есть примеры оформления текста письма в художественном произведении (кавычки, курсив, пустые строки, ещё что-то)? И можно ли такие короткие фрагменты писать как обычную цитату? Например:

Он вновь развернул пергамент и торопливо приписал: "Остаток лета я пробуду у моего друга Рона Уизли. Пиши мне туда. Его папа достал билеты на Чемпионат мира по квиддичу!"

**Дополнено**

В книге "Белая гвардия" (М. Булгаков, изд. "Детская литература", 2020 г.) текст письма оформлен меньшим размером шрифта и тоже отделён от основного текста пустыми строками.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не надо — лучше, надо оформлять правильно.

Answer (score 2):

Пустые строки называются отбивки. Да, такой вариант оформления совершенно корректен и глазу приятен.

Можете, конечно, и кавычить, и даже (страшно сказать!) сохранить при кавычках и курсив с отбивками, и даже всё перечисленное, исполненное болдом, - нетути криминала, это книжнодизайнерские выкрутасы.

К русскому языку всё это отношения не имеет, исходим из: смотрится - не смотрится. (Однако - *если текст рукописный* - кавычки без отбивок.)

Ну кто будет искать примеры? Я Полиграфический (ныне акадЭмия) окончила, верьте на слово.

Answer (score 1):

В тексте на снимке цитата должна была начаться с тире, означающем и знак прямой речи, и всякую иную фразу, ранее произнесённую, написанную, мысленную.
Цитаты заключаются в кавычки, независимо от слова, её предваряющего
(*указывал*, *напомнил*, *рекомендовал*, *учил*). Есть исключения из правил
цитирования: стихотворные цитаты и эпиграфы не выделяются кавычками.

> Белинский писал:  «Создаёт человека природа, но развивает и образует
> его общество»;
>
> «Двенадцать миллионов людей вне закона!.. Ужас!»  — писал в своём
> дневнике А. И. Герцен, имея в виду крепостных крестьян в тогдашней
> России;
>
> «Первоэлементом литературы, — указывал М. Горький, — является язык,
> основное орудие её и — вместе с фактами, явлениями жизни — материал
> литературы»;
>
> Докладчик привёл слова М. В. Ломоносова: «России могущество будет
> прирастать Сибирью» — и этим закончил своё выступление.

https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL05/71827540.html?ysclid=l85sp70jqj322598687

Оформление данного фрагмента могло бы строиться на рукописном (не курсивном!) варианте, либо тонированном (рамочном) решении, делающем излишними знаки препинания при прямой речи.

Answer (score 1):

**I.** Приведу примеры оформления письма (рукописи, манускрипта) из "Собаки Баскервилей".

**1.** Холмс прислонился к спинке кресла, сложил вместе кончики пальцев обеих рук и закрыл глаза с выражением покорности. Доктор Мортимер повернул рукопись к свету и стал читать высоким, надтреснутым голосом следующий любопытный рассказ:

*«Много говорилось о происхождении Баскервильской собаки, но так как я происхожу по прямой линии от Гюго Баскервиля, и так как я слышал эту историю от моего отца, а он от своего, то я изложил ее с полною уверенностью, что она произошла именно так, как тут изложена...».*

Еще так: «Много говорилось о происхождении Баскервильской собаки...».
И так: ***«Много говорилось о происхождении Баскервильской собаки...».***

**2.** Откинувшись на спинку кресла, Холмc сомкнул концы пальцев и  с  видом
полной покорности судьбе закрыл глаза. Доктор Мортимер повернулся к  свету
и высоким скрипучим голосом начал читать нам следующую любопытную  повесть
древних времен:

— «Много есть свидетельств о собаке Баскервилей, но,  будучи  прямым
потомком Гуго Баскервиля и будучи наслышан о сей собаке от отца своего,  а
он — от моего деда, я положил себе записать сию  историю,  в  подлинности
коей не может быть сомнений...».

Имеется вариант  и без отбивки (это способ нешрифтового выделения текста путем увеличения пробелов между отдельными его фрагментами).

**II.** А вот пример классического оформления обычного письма.

> Она принесла на веранду большой блокнот, вместе с конвертами и шариковой ручкой уложенный в чемодан дедушкой, села у слезящегося окна и стала писать первое письмо: "Милый дедушка! Вот я доехала. Стихийных бедствий по дороге не было. Разбойники, пираты и замаскированные диверсанты на меня не кидались. Все ценности, захваченные в дорогу, я довезла в сохранности, кроме куриной ноги и бутербродов с котлетами, которые я съела, как только поезд отошел..."
> Она улыбнулась, представив себе, как дедушка будет это читать, и продолжала:
> "Я уже пообедала. Кормят не особенно, но много. Теперь сижу на веранде и наслаждаюсь заслуженным отдыхом. Море где-то рядом, но я еще не ходила: очень уж дождь.
> <...>
> Целую тебя, мой миленький, в твою окладистую бороду, которую ты когда-нибудь соберешься отрастить.
> Остаюсь твоя внучка, дочка, а также старая бабка — Лина.
> Сердечный привет Тюфякину. Л.".
> [Федор Кнорре. Весенняя путевка](https://www.litmir.me/br/?b=59432)

Он вновь развернул пергамент и торопливо приписал: "Остаток лета я пробуду у моего друга Рона Уизли. Пиши мне туда. Его папа достал билеты на Чемпионат мира по квиддичу!"
Конечно же, так совсем даже не возбраняется, это стандартное решение.

**III.** В той же "Собаке Баскервилей" письма доктора оформлены вообще отдельной главой.

IX. Второе донесение доктора Ватсона. Свет на болоте

***Баскервиль-голль, октября 15-го.***

«Дорогой Холмс, если вы не получали от меня особенных новостей...».

```
    Фоновое выделение
```

тоже возможно, но так обычно делают, когда письмо цитируется.